# Is it possible to store a Boost uint128_t datatype into a primitive int?

Tags: c++, boost

I was experimenting with the Boost library and wanted to store a value in a uint128_t datatype defined in Boost 1.59.0 into a primitive int type. The uint128_t has the value, say 0xaf which can fit into an int. Essentially what I am trying to do is:

```
uint128_t var = 0xaf;
int new_var = var;
```

I cannot do this directly. Is there anyway this can be done? I need to downcast it into a primitive type so that I can use it as an index to an array. I tried going through the Boost documentation but got a bit confused. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you expect to store 128 bits of data in 32 bits? Magic?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Comment: @SLaks The question says that the value is in `int`'s range, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Generally the answer to "how do I use this library" is to **check the documentation**.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking the way a float can be stored in an int with loss of precision. But then I realised that a float is 32 bit as well. I guess if I access the memory location directly? I only need to access 8 bits of data.

Comment: There was no mention in the Boost documentation. I may have missed it. I will check again.

Comment: By the way, this question is a very good improvement over your earlier attempt at asking the same thing, keep that up.

Comment: You have to use explicit cast notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost's `number` class has a member function template for conversions:

```
template <class T>
T convert_to()const;
```

as well as an explicit conversion operator template, so `static_cast<T>(number)` may work, though [according to the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/conversions.html) that can be specific to the back-end storage type used.

Comment: The explicit conversion operator template didn't work for me. But the member function template worked!